# How can I make a loop that will add class from hours in moment.js?

Tags: javascript, loops, time, momentjs

How can I create a loop that allows me to add a class to a container div to change its color based off what hour it is? Like if the hour has passed, then the class would be "past" and then I could assign it a color based off that. I'm having an issue with my for loop and getting error messaged about 'blockHour' not being defined.

Here is my JS:

```
var saveBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('saveBtn');
var timeContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('timeContainer');
var btnContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('btnContainer');
var time = document.getElementsByClassName('time');
const currentHour = moment().format('HH');

// Below is moment.js to auto-update time on webpage----------//
var update = function () {
    date = moment(new Date())
    currentDay.html(date.format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, HH:mm:ss a'));
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    currentDay = $('#currentDay')
    update();
    setInterval(update, 1000);
});
for (let blockHour = 9; blockHour < 18; blockHour++) {

    var blockHour = parseInt("hour"[1]);

    console.log( blockHour, currentHour)

    if (blockHour < currentHour) {
        timeContainer.addClass("past");
    }
    else if (blockHour === currentHour) {
        timeContainer.addClass("present");
    }
    else {
        timeContainer.addClass("future");
    }
};
```

And here is some of my HTML (specifically just the container):

```
 <tr class="timeContainer" id="timecontainer">
            <th scope="time" id="hour9" class="time">09:00</th>
            <td><input type="text" class="textbox"></td>
            <td class="btnContainer">
              <button class="saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
            </td>
          </tr>
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: FYI your javascript is not valid. Error at `var blockHour = parseInt("hour"[1]);` also this line makes no sense. Please provide a ​​[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

create an object with colors and hours like:

```
const hourToColor = {'1': 'red', '2': 'blue'};
```

then access it in your loop by index like:

```
hourToColor[index]; // will return you 'red' in case when index === 1
```

hope that makes sense

Comment: Technically you don't need an object, a simple array will do the trick too.

Comment: Yeah you are absolutely right. I suggested to use an object just for better understanding what is going on.